# The active tab in the list iems don't show Bootstrap angular [ngClass]

Tags: angular, list, bootstrap-4, tabs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VemM.png)I have a list of roles which I would like to show with a list group of Bootstrap (role=tab).

The normal behavior is to show the active element (in the list) tab.

But in my case it doesn't work.

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <div class="list-group" id="myList" role="tablist">
          <a *ngFor="let role of Roles" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="list"
            href="#{{deletewhitespace(role)}}" role="tab" (click)="rendertabel()"    
            [ngClass]="{ 'active' :Roles.indexOf(role)==0 }"> 
//this is where i put active class for the first role only 
{{role}}</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Tab panes -->
      <div class="col-10">
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div *ngFor="let role of Roles" class="tab-pane" id="{{deletewhitespace(role)}}" role="tabpanel">
            <div class="card-title">{{role}}</div> <br>
    //tab content


            <div class="row justify-content-end">
              <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Second group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm "
                  (click)="SavePermissionConfigurations()">Sauvegarder les changements</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
```

this is how its rendred 
and this is how it should be

Comment: are you using jQuery in Angular... and not https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/tabs or https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabset/examples or https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/components/tabs/ ??

Comment: thanks a lot for the response, i am using bootstrap as css provider so i am importing the Bootstrap css an js wich uses jquery in order to work.  this is the element that i use https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/list-group/#javascript-behavior.

Comment: jquery with Angular wouldn't work... you gotta go for a bootstrap library for Angular... i suggested 3 of these in my previous comment